# Java: Extract content from MTOM

Tags: java, soap, mtom

I'm trying to extract content of a MTOM using code below

```
Iterator i = msg.getAttachments();
while (i.hasNext())
{
  AttachmentPart att = (AttachmentPart)i.next();
  Object obj = att.getContent();
}
```

where `msg` is `SOAPMessage` MIME type but the rawContent comes as `null` and will crash on getting `AttachmentPart`

Is there any other way to get MTOM content? Getting boundaries and looping through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up with the code below

```
 MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart(new ByteArrayDataSource(InputStream, "multipart/related"));
 int count = mp.getCount();
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     BodyPart bodyPart = mp.getBodyPart(i);
     String content = new String(read(bodyPart));

     String partContentType =  bodyPart.getContentType();


  if(partContentType.toLowerCase().contains(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_CONTENT_TYPE)) {

        //process SOAP 1.2
     }

    if(partContentType.toLowerCase().contains(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_CONTENT_TYPE)) {

        //process SOAP 1.1
     }

     if(partContentType.toLowerCase().contains("application/octet-stream")) {

        // process binary part
     }
 }
```